# IntelliJ doesn't recognize main but only in our shared repository

Tags: github, intellij-idea, classpath, program-entry-point, javac

I am a student and we have an assignment where we collaborate on a github shared repository. Me and another student in our group have the same problem: On our computers IntelliJ cannot find the Main class and compile it.

On my other projects, running Mains is not a problem and therefore I can't find any help through the search results I get from Google and Youtube.

Can't even click run since the run configurations are weird too, but I fixed that before and the Main class-problem remained. That problem came back now since I've tried to re-clone the project a few times now... The other 3 students in the group can run Main. I don't know if it has anything to do with it but we don't have a src -folder, is that confusing the compiler or anything?

Would really appreciate some help.
[Picture: It doesn't compile.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AceDa.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> don't know if it has anything to do with it but we don't have a src -folder, is that confusing the compiler or anything?

It can be for IntelliJ, managing a Java project.
Check if you can define your ['`sample`' folder as a source root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#folder-categories), which would force IntelliJ to consider the sources inside `sample` as a program to compile.